# convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{\log (1 +\frac {1}{n})}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Test convergence of $$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac {1}{\log (1 +\frac {1}{n})}$$

I am not really sure how to move forward. Could anyone give me a direction to proceed please.

**EDIT"** The only part I could think of was : $\ln ( 1+ \frac {1}{n}) \leq 1 + \frac {1}{n}$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you thought about this? What do you know about the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+x)$ for $x$ near $0$? What does this tell you about $\log(1+1/n)$ for $n$ big? In particular, $\log(1+x)\sim x$ for $x$ small... so? (Perhaps you mean $\log(1+1/n)$ and not its reciprocal, since $\log 1=0$.

Comment: The necessary condition for convergence fails.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @AaronMaroja No not homework. I was trying out problems from Apostol by myself.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks. I have edited the original question. It's still the same except $n$ varies from $2$

Comment: @Wanderer Try showing some of your work.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Edited my question.

Comment: @Wanderer Cool! Now use idm 's argument!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq\frac{1}{n}\implies \frac{1}{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\geq n$$
and thus the serie doesn't converge.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how I can prove that $\ln(1+1/n)≤1/n$. I thought of going the same way but couldn't prove it satisfactorily

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Actually, that should read $\dfrac1{\ln\Big(1+\tfrac1n\Big)}\geq n$.

Comment: @Lucian: I corrected it, tks very much :-)

Comment: But it is well-known that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=\zeta(-1)$ converges to $-\dfrac1{12}$ , so your conclusion must be wrong. ;-$)$

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty }n=\infty $ therefore the series can't converge !

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

If the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Use the contrapositive in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You could have also used the trivial criterium:

Define 
$a_{n}:=ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Then one has $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} =ln\left(1\right)=0$

Thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{a_{n}}=\infty$.

Therefore the above series can not converge, since $\frac{1}{a_{n}}$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment by user121270, who stated the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. makes perfect sense. I think I am just worn out a little :(